# AppArmor with cupsd denied in logs

Tags: permissions, printing, apparmor

I was updating the OS today (security patches), when I found something strange in the syslog:

`apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2483 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"`

It appeared in the syslog 5 times.

I never saw this log, so I started to look about it, but no success. the only thing I know is that cupsd is something about printer (something that I never used with Ubuntu).

So, I also took a look into the `/log/cups/access_log` and I found this (looking at the timestamp, this log came 1 second before the log from the syslog):

`localhost - - [07/Jul/2015:11:49:50 -0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3695675 CUPS-Get-PPDs -`

So, I never had any DENIED thing from apparmor. Anyone knows why this happenned? Also note that I never had to use a printer with Ubuntu.

Thank you guys for helping me.

EDIT: Just noticed that in the same day that I downloaded the updates, I also installed updates for the `cups`. Maybe that's why it had the DENIED log?

Answer (score 18):

Workaround from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#AppArmor_Protection_of_the_printing_system

Make sure `apparmor-utils` is installed: `apt-get install apparmor-utils`

If you have any problems with printing, try deactivating the AppArmor protection with `sudo aa-complain cupsd`. Note after doing this I had to unplug and replug the printer for it to work.

You can re-activate AppArmor via `sudo aa-enforce cupsd`.

> If this helps, look for messages containing audit in the
>   /var/log/syslog file. These show which components are accessed by the
>   printing system for which there is no explicit permission given in
>   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd

More details in the above link. (They also want you to report the bug).

Comment: Same thing on Debian 11 - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980974